# How to get access token while connecting to Google Drive via Apex code

Tags: apex

I am trying to get access token while calling Google drive API from apex code.

```
public void uploadopportunitydata(List<Opportunity> opp){
//String accessToken = Auth.AuthToken.getAccessToken('0SO6C000000008c', 'Open ID connect');

     //system.debug('access token'+ accessToken);

    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setMethod('POST');
    req.setEndpoint('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token');
    req.setHeader('content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    String messageBody = 'code='+ '0SO6C000000004c' +'&client_id='+ '1034028321348-g3ursbjeolg9n3e9u5aqs51tfn84ieck.apps.googleusercontent.com'+'&client_secret='+EhemvpeM1WAGtkLT4zMvQUZH+'&redirect_uri='+ 'https://salesforcedomain/services/authcallback/MyGoogleProvider'+'&grant_type'='authorization_code';

    req.setHeader('Content-length', String.valueOf(messageBody.length()));
    req.setBody(messageBody);
    req.setTimeout(60*1000);


    Http h = new Http();
    String resp;
    HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
    resp = res.getBody();




    JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(resp);
    while (parser.nextToken() != null) {
    if ((parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME)){
    String fieldName = parser.getText();
    parser.nextToken();
    if(fieldName == 'access_token')
    {
        accesstoken = parser.getText();
    }

  }

 }



}
```

I keep getting syntax/compile error at the following line. What am I doing wrong here? Also, I have added Auth provider ID(in salesforce) as the code value below.  Is that right?

```
 String messageBody = 'code='+ '0SO6C000000004c' +
            '&client_id='+
                      '1060428321348-g3ursbjeolg9n3e9u5aqs51tfn84ieck.apps.googleusercontent.com'+

            '&client_secret='+EhjdPpeM1WAGtkLT4zMvQUZH+
            '&redirect_uri='+  
            'https://salesforcedomain/services/authcallback/MyGoogleProvider'+
            '&grant_type'='authorization_code';
```

Comment: you are exposing your client secret on a public forum; the line in error is `'&client_secret='+thesecretstring+` and should be `'&client_secret='+'thesecretstring'+`

Comment: Those are fake ids. Also I tried putting client secret in string, it still gives me the same error  Compile Error: Expression cannot be assigned at line 14 column 28. Line 14 is the line I shared above.

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape your single quotes inside of strings. Where you wrote:

`'&grant_type'='authorization_code';`

you needed to write

`'&grant_type=\'authorization_code\'';`

Or, if `authorization_code` is a string, then write

`'&grant_type='+'authorization_code';`